# Running multiple instances of BlueStacks at the same time for development

Tags: android, bluestacks

I want to know if I can use two instances of BlueStacks at the same time for testing my apps with different resolutions. I drew out a rough sketch just in case to explain my theories.

Rough sketch:

[image: Test application running at two resolutions]

Emulator 1 - 720 x 1280 phone

Emulator 2 - 1280 x 768 tablet

Is it possible to run multiple instances of BlueStacks? If not, then is there a way to change to different resolutions for testing apps in various screen sizes of Android phones and tablets?

P.S. I could have used other emulators like Genymotion, or AVD from Android Studio itself, but I am on an AMD machine, which rules out the AVD from Android Studio as I believe it only works on Intel, and Genymotion is extremely slow.

In case you are wondering if my laptop is that weak, why I would want to use BlueStacks at all, let alone two instances at the same time, here are my laptop specifications:

```
Processor: AMD A8 Quadcore 7410 APU with 1GB Radeon R5 graphics
Graphics:  AMD Radeon R5 M335 2GB Graphics Card Built-in
RAM:       8 GB
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as genymotion goes, It is really really slow and puts a load on my machine. But bluestacks seems to run fast and smooth. Two or three instances of bluestacks won't be a problem for my machine.

Comment: Bluestacks might have gotten faster, or people have started buying good/newer hardware. Now, new versions of bluestacks, may conversely have problems running on older systems due to driver and hardware support issues. But yeah, bluestacks has gotten faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to run multiple instances of an app, see [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-the-same-program-on-your-pc/). To summarise, here are some methods:

- Shift-clicking the icon may work for some applications
- **Since the instance is tied to your user account, you can run as a different user**
- **Isolate the instances with a program such as Sandboxie**
- Use any built-in tools of the application (see below)

[BlueStacks 4](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033777052) (and [BlueStacks 3](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003172406-Introducing-BlueStacks-3-multiple-instances)) (on Windows only currently) allows running multiple instances inside BlueStacks, using the Instance Manger, but I'm not sure exactly how that works, since I have a Mac.

Comment: I am aware that when the question was asked, neither BlueStacks 3 nor 4 had been released. However, I have provided alternate methods. ;)